# android system-app update needs rebooting device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I have to update app which is present under `/system/priv-app/` using `adb install -r "APK path "`.After installation version name is changing to latest in setting app.but once i open app first time it crashes and then runs with old code.I added only one line log in new version, result was same app crashed with `ResourceNotFound` Exception.

After long struggle i tried rebooting phone then it is working fine.One more thing I would like to add is previous app was built on `Eclipse` and update is built on `Android studio`.

Attached logs-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(21895): Process: com.app, PID: 21895
E/AndroidRuntime(21895): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.AppActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2600)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1469)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5622)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:420)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2195)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at com.app.AppActivity.onCreate(AppActivity.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6120)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2467)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(21895): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    ... 23 more
E/AndroidRuntime(21895): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a002a
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1457)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:1051)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at com.app.ui.CirclePageIndicator.<init>(CirclePageIndicator.java:82)
E/AndroidRuntime(21895):    at com.app.ui.CirclePageIndicator.<init>(CirclePageIndicator.java:72)
```

Comment: remove app from your device, clean and rebuild your project. Then run the app

Comment: I can't remove app from device as i am giving update for system app although i tried cleaning and building,it does't work.

Comment: I have attached logs.One more thing if i am installing through Package Manager most of the time its working fine.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you manage to fix this ?

Comment: Do you have `android:persistent` in previous version ?